# Is it possible to define converter for binding inline (without resource)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to define type converter for binding inline (without resource)?

Something like this:

```
   <Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=checkBox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={new BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create and expose your converter through a custom `MarkupExtension` which will give you the inline declaration you're looking for:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverterExtension : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
  private BooleanToVisibilityConverter converter;

  public BooleanToVisibilityCoverterExtension() : base()
  {
    this.converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter();
  }

  public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
    return this;
  }

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return this.converter.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return this.converter.ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
  }
}
```

Now you can use the MarkupExtension inline to create a new converter:

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding Converter={local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter} ...}" .. />
```

Comment: and while I don't show it in my example, you'd probably want to make the internal converter static so that each extension doesn't create a new instance of the internal converter

Comment: Cool! In combination with generic `ValueConverter<T, U>` and markup constructor parameters syntax (to pass for example boolean NOT argument) it will be very nice solution.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible using binding syntax. But it is possible using element syntax:

```
 <Button.Visibility>
    <Binding ElementName="checkBox" Path=IsChecked>
        <Binding.Converter>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter />
        </Binding.Converter>
    </Binding>
 </Button.Visibility>
```

But **why** would you want to do this? It would mean every binding instance will create a new converter. That's not efficient from a memory point of view.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this. This **should** work.

***Pseudocode***:

```
public static class ConverterHost 
{ 
    public static readonly MyCoolConverter converter = new MyCoolConverter (); 
}
```

and in the XAML, somethign like this:

```
{Binding Converter={x:Static conv:ConverterHost.converter }}
```

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to define the converter as a resource somewhere (window, usercontrol, etc.) before you can use it in a binding.

Comment: Not true, you can derive a converter from MarkupExtension and avoid the definition as a resource.